# Unique intermediate subgroup and double coset relation I

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup such that there is a **unique**   (non-trivial) intermediate subgroup $K$  (i.e. $H < S < G$ implies $S=K$).

> **Question**: Is it true that $HgK=KgH$, $\forall g \in G$ ?

**Experiment** (GAP) : It's true if $[G:H] \le 30$ and $\vert G/H_G \vert \le 10000$.
($H_G$ is the [normal core](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_core) of $H$ in $G$)

Comment: See the augmented question: [Unique intermediate subgroup and double coset relation II](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723730/unique-intermediate-subgroup-and-double-coset-relation-ii)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are counterexamples with $G = {\rm PSL}(2,11)$, $H$ cyclic of order $6$ and $K$ dihedral of order $12$.

I find it difficult to understand why you would expect such a property to be true.
The reason why it holds in many small examples is that $HgK=KgK=KgH$.

Comment: Thank you! $\vert G/H_G \vert \le 10000$, it's not so small examples. Do you suspect it's true if $[G:H] \le 30$ without restriction on the order of $G/H_G$ ? If yes, is there a proof without computation ?

Comment: Since there are databases of permutation groups of degree up to $30$, it could be checked by computer for $|G:H| \le 30$. I find it very unlikely that there would be acomputer-free proof.

Comment: Yes, I've used the databases of transitive permutation groups, but beyond order $10000$, the verification begins to be long for my computer. I think I can't check this with my own  computer in a reasonable time.

Comment: I've checked it already! The unique intermediate condition is equivalent to there being a unique system of blocks of imprimitivity, which is easy to check. For such groups, take $H$ to be a point stabilizer, and $K$ the stabilizer of a block containing that point. I found that for all such groups of degree up to 30, the number of double cosets $KgK$ was equal to the number of double cosets $HgK$, so we always get $HgK = KgH = KgK$.

Comment: It's a quite strange phenomenon that this property is true for all the transitive groups of degree up to $30$, but not in general. Perhaps your counterexample of degree $110$ is the first. I've also found a counterexample of degree $182$ with $G=PSL(2,13)$, $K=D_{12}$ and $H=S_3$.

Comment: Perhaps there is a proof by using an assumption like $1/3<\frac{[G:K]}{[K:H]}<3$ or $1/2<\frac{[G:K]}{[K:H]}<2$ or $[G:K]=[K:H]$ or $(K \subset G) \sim (H \subset K)$.

Comment: I allowed myself to post an augmented question III [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724877/unique-intermediate-subgroup-and-double-coset-relation-iii-homogeneity-assumpti), with the additional assumption $(H \subset K) \sim (K \subset G)$ (I hope my  augmented questions do not annoy the users). Do you think it's also false with this additional assumption ? (Perhaps the counter-examples are much harder to find because $G$ can't be a finite simple group; or perhaps it's true).