# Unique intermediate subgroup and double coset relation II

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup such that there is a **unique** (non-trivial) intermediate subgroup $K$  (i.e. $H < S < G$ implies $S=K$).

> **Question**: Is there $\alpha \ge 1$ such that if $1/\alpha \le \frac{[G:K]}{[K:H]} \le \alpha$ then $HgK=KgH$, $\forall g \in G$ ?

**Experiment** : If $[G:H] \le 30$ then it's true for all $\alpha \ge 1$ (see [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720542/a-relation-for-the-inclusions-of-groups-with-a-unique-intermediate/721164#comment1507674_721164) of Derek Holt).

**If it's true** in general, let $\alpha_M$ be the maximum of the allowed $\alpha$.
Thanks to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720542/a-relation-for-the-inclusions-of-groups-with-a-unique-intermediate/721164#721164) we know that $\alpha_M \le 55/2$.

> What do we know about $\alpha_M$ ? (a better upper-bound? integer, rational or irrational? its value?)

Comment: It's an augmented question of: [Unique intermediate subgroup and double coset relation I](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720542/unique-intermediate-subgroup-and-double-coset-relation-i)

Comment: So the first two lines **simply** say that $\;H\;$ is a (proper) maximal subgroup of $\;G\;$ , right?

Comment: @DonAntonio: No

Comment: Ok @Sebastien, then: "there is a unique and non-trivial intermediate subgroup $\;K\;$ ...." **where** ? Between $\;H\;$ and $\;G\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes

Comment: So then $\;H\;$ is a maximal proper subgroup of a maximal proper subgroup of $\;G\;$ ...gotcha!

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes, but in addition, the non-trivial intermediate subgroup $K$, between $H$ and $G$, is **unique**. If $G=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\{e\}$, then $H$ is a maximal proper subgroup of a maximal proper subgroup of $G$, but if $H < S < G$ then $S=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} $ or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $ (it's not unique). Now if $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\{e\}$, then $H$ is a maximal proper subgroup of a maximal proper subgroup of $G$, and if $H < S < G$ then $S=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $ (it's unique).

Comment: See the augmented question: [Unique intermediate subgroup and double coset relation III (homogeneity assumption)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724877/unique-intermediate-subgroup-and-double-coset-relation-iii-homogeneity-assumpti)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, see [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723030/is-there-a-simple-group-and-a-proper-subgroup-with-a-unique-and-equidistant-inte/723797#comment1513679_723797) of Derek Holt announcing a counterexample for $\alpha=1$

**Counter-example**: << $A_{10}$ with a subgroup of index $120$ (the setwise stabilizer of three points), which itself has a maximal subgroup of index $120$ >>.

**Some details**:

```
gap> G:=AlternatingGroup(10);   
Alt( [ 1 .. 10 ] )
gap> H:=Group([ (8,9,10), (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), (2,3,5)(4,7,6), (2,7)(3,6)(4,5)(9,10) ]);
Group([ (8,9,10), (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), (2,3,5)(4,7,6), (2,7)(3,6)(4,5)(9,10) ])
gap> IntermediateSubgroups(G,H);
rec( subgroups := [ Group([ (2,7)(3,6)(4,5)(9,10), (2,3,5)(4,7,6), (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), (8,9,10), (6,7)(9,10) ]) ], 
  inclusions := [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ] ] )
gap> K:=Group([ (2,7)(3,6)(4,5)(9,10), (2,3,5)(4,7,6), (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), (8,9,10), (6,7)(9,10) ]);
Group([ (2,7)(3,6)(4,5)(9,10), (2,3,5)(4,7,6), (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), (8,9,10), (6,7)(9,10) ])
gap> Size(G); Size(K); Size(H);
1814400
15120
126
gap> IsNormalIntermediate(G,H,K);
false
```

Using the following function:

```
IsNormalIntermediate:=function(G,H,K)
    local D1,D2,s,i,j,E1,E2,c;
    D1:=DoubleCosets(G,H,K);
    s:=Size(DoubleCosets(G,H,K));
    c:=0;
    if s=Size(DoubleCosets(G,K,K)) then
        return true;
    else
        D2:=DoubleCosets(G,K,H);
        for i in [1..s] do 
            for j in [1..s] do
                E1:=Elements(D1[i]);
                E2:=Elements(D2[j]);
                if Size(E1)=Size(E2) then
                    if E1=E2 then
                        c:=c+1;
                    fi;
                fi;
            od;
        od; 
    fi;
    return c=s;
end;;
```